# browser connection with server socket in c

Tags: serversocket

i'm a beginner in network programming and i have a project in which i have to create a system explorer. That means that i will have the ability to write a http request with a directory in a browser and if the connection with the server is succesfull, the files from the above directory will open.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
typedef struct tcpip_connection
{
int connfd;         
struct sockaddr_in peer_addr;   
} tcpip_connection;


int s_socket, *fd, port;
char buffer[256];
struct sockaddr_in lis_addr;
struct sockaddr_in peer_addr;
int sopt = 1, n;


s_socket=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 

if(s_socket<0){ 
printf("error: the socket was not created!");
}

if(setsockopt(s_socket , SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &sopt, sizeof(sopt))){ 
printf("Setsokopt error!");
}

memset(&lis_addr, 0, sizeof(lis_addr));
lis_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
lis_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
lis_addr.sin_port = htons(port);


if ( bind( s_socket, (struct sockaddr*) &lis_addr, sizeof(lis_addr) ) < 0 ){            
  perror(NULL);                             
  exit(-1);
}

if(listen(s_socket,15)<0){       
perror("server.listen");
}

socklen_t peer_addrlen;


while(1){

if((fd = malloc(sizeof(int))) == NULL){
fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory\n");
abort();
}
*fd=accept(s_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&peer_addr,&peer_addrlen);

if(fd<0){
if( errno==EINTR           /* Call interrupted by signal */
|| errno==ECONNABORTED  /* connection was aborted */
|| errno==EMFILE       /* per-process limit of open fds */
|| errno==ENFILE       /* system-wide limit of open fds */
|| errno==ENOBUFS      /* no space for socket buffers */
|| errno==ENOMEM       /* no space for socket buffers */
|| errno==EPERM    /* Firewall blocked the connection */
)
continue;

}

}

if(errno == EBADF)
break;          /* return, the server_socket is closed */
}

bzero(buffer,1024);
n = read(*fd,buffer,1023);
if (n < 0)
{
perror("ERROR reading from socket");
exit(1);
}
printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);


/* Write a response to the client 

n = write(*fd,"I got your message",18);
if (n < 0)
{
perror("ERROR writing to socket");
exit(1);
}
return 0;*/



}
```

I don't know if there is anything wrong with my code, but the main problem is that i don't know how to make the browser connect with the server. Is there anything i have to write in the browser or do i have to add some extra code?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize the port variable. Try setting `port = 8080` before you call bind and listen.

Then, in your browser, go to `http://localhost:8080/` and it should connect.

Comment: i did it and it still doesn't work. Only by initializing the port, will i have the ability to connect?I mean is that so easy, because i thought i would be mush more difficult.

Comment: You did most the necessary stuff already (though I didn't run your code, it didn't compile, maybe due to copy/paste problems), but getting a server started is: create a socket, bind it to the address (the port is important here), then call listen. Once you're listening, you can accept connections and start talking on them. When you go to the address in your browser, you'll immediately see data on the socket.